# JavaScript Passing in a function to map();

Tags: javascript, es6-map

Can someone please explain how the below code working?

```
...

articles.map(createArticle).join("\n");

function createArticle(article){
  return `
    <div class="article">
      <h1>${article.news}</h1>
    </div>
  `
}
```

I understand how `map();` works, I just don't understand where it gets article from as its not being passed as an argument to the createArticle function within `map();`

Comment: This is how `.map` function works: it invokes a specified callback for each element of an array, passing this element into that callback as a parameter.

Comment: article is the content of each item in the array, articles ... the callback "signature" is `function(item, index, array)` ... of course, in the callback function you can call those arguments what you like, in this case `article` and you don't have to use the 2nd and 3rd, which is the case

Comment: I don't get it ... you understand how map works ... but you don't actually understand how map works, because you don't know how the callback function is called - [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Syntax) may help

Comment: @Ollie Basically map is passing an object of articles to createArticle method  that readout the news and join will concatenating the new with new line
I have added a simple example  below it will help to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `createArticle` function is actually being passed 3 arguments: the item in the array, the index of the item and the array.

```
articles.map(function createArticle(article, i, arr) {
    return `
        <div class="article">
            <h1>${article.news}</h1>
        </div>
    `
});
```

Your code is just changing the `createArticle` function from an anonymous function into a named one.

```
articles.map(createArticle);

function createArticle(article, i, arr) {
    return `
        <div class="article">
            <h1>${article.news}</h1>
        </div>
    `
}
```

Since parameters don't need to be declared in JavaScript, your code doesn't include the `i` or `arr` parameters.

```
articles.map(createArticle);

function createArticle(article) {
    return `
        <div class="article">
            <h1>${article.news}</h1>
        </div>
    `
}
```

You can see a full explaination and a polyfill (unnecessary these days, but can be helpful when trying to understand a function) on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> `map` calls a provided `callback` function **once for each element** in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results.

So, the `argument` refers to the each and every element; during the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

createArticle is the callback called on each element of the articles array.

> [As explained in the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), "callback is invoked with three
>   arguments: **the value of the element**, the index of the element, and the
>   Array object being traversed."

So here, article is the value of the current element being iterated on.

Answer (score 0):

The function `createArticle` is passed as an argument to `map`.

The code for `map` (which you didn't write, is built into the JavaScript engine, and is not visible in the code you copy/pasted as a consequence of that) **calls** `createArticle` (which it has access to because you passed it as an argument). Since *that* code is calling it (once for each element in the array), it can pass `createArticle` whatever arguments it likes.

The arguments it passes are documented wherever `map` is documented, including:

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Ecma](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.map)

Answer (score -1):

```
var persons = [
    {firstname : "Deepak", lastname: "Patidar"},      
    {firstname : "Anjular", lastname: "5"},
    {firstname : "Java", lastname: "script"}
];


function getFullName(item,index) {
    var fullname = [item.firstname,item.lastname].join(" ");
    return fullname;
}

function myFunction() { 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = persons.map(getFullName);
}
```